# Serializing the driver's init call order, which were registered at the same init level

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have come across a scenario where two drivers (driver1 and driver2) are registering with kernel using **module_init()**. driver1 is configuring the chip and driver2 is accessing that chip, so driver1's **module_init()** has to be called before driver2's **module_init()** call. How we can create this order, as both driver1 and driver2 are registering at the same init call level (i.e using **module_init()**).

Comment: There is the missing information. Are they using APIs from one in the other? Are the functionality of one of them is optional to the other? Why do you need an order bettween them?

Comment: @0andriy, I need to access SPI device. For this the SPI interface driver should be registered before my driver. So that the SPI message calls from my driver will be success. Both the drivers source files are placed under their own subfolders and these subfolders are under drivers folder of Kernel source tree.

Comment: So, you have SPI device provided via device tree, right? SPI core will defer the probe of your driver until the device appears. I don't see anything you need to do in the code, except properly formed Device Tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can driver2 somehow determine that the chip has been properly configured, using either device status (preferred) or the value of a shared variable (messy)?
If so, then driver2's probe routine should return with -EPROBE_DEFER when the chip has not yet been configured (by driver1).

See https://lwn.net/Articles/485194/

```
drivercore: Add driver probe deferral mechanism 

Allow drivers to report at probe time that they cannot get all the resources
required by the device, and should be retried at a later time.

This should completely solve the problem of getting devices
initialized in the right order.  Right now this is mostly handled by
mucking about with initcall ordering which is a complete hack, and
doesn't even remotely handle the case where device drivers are in
modules.  This approach completely sidesteps the issues by allowing
driver registration to occur in any order, and any driver can request
to be retried after a few more other drivers get probed.
```

Comment: Thanks for deferred probe approach. I need to communicate to SPI device from my driver. First I am checking required SPI device using device iterator func(deferred probing helps here, i.e if device is not available then I can use deferral mechanism). After device is available, need to communicate with the device using SPI subsystem funcs, so for this SPI modules should be registered first. If I add my drivers entry in drivers/Makefile after spi entries then I could see the init calls in System.map also coming in the same order. I think at boot time init calls will be called as per  System.map.

Comment: @RaviA, you are doing something really unneeded at all. Linux supports Device Tree and ACPI for the platform description where all these kind of problems are solved already.