# device tree devices binding order with the device drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I have a requirement to send a reset signal to a switch using GPIO before the ethernet controller is configured (i.e. before ethernet controller driver and device binding). I have added the reset logic in the GPIO controller driver and gpio controller device node entry in the device tree. It is working fine.

I have converted final dtb file to dts and checked the device nodes order, the ethernet controller device node is ahead of gpio controller device node. But during boot time GPIO controller driver binding is happening before ethernet controller driver binding, so it is working fine. I have restarted multiple times and observed that GPIO controller is coming before ethernet controller always.

Is there any place where the device tree device nodes binding order is updated. My concern is that if ethernet controller driver binding happens before GPIO controller then the functionality will not work.

How the device tree device nodes binding order is decided?

Answer (score 0):

> But during boot time GPIO controller driver binding is happening before ethernet controller driver binding,

Instead of "*binding*", you presumably mean driver initialization.
Linux kernel **Documentation/driver-api/driver-model/binding.rst** defines *driver binding* as "*the process of associating a device with a device driver that can control it.*"
(The Linux kernel tends to combine or conflate the driver initialization with device probing & binding, especially at boot time.)

Your gpio controller driver probably declares its initialization routine using the **subsys_initcall()** macro.
Whereas your Ethernet (MAC?) driver probably declares its initialization routine using the **module_init()** macro.

See [What is the difference between module_init and subsys_initcall while initializing the driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541290/what-is-the-difference-between-module-init-and-subsys-initcall-while-initializin/15542788#15542788)

Bottom line: the driver using **subsys_initcall()** is meant to always be initialized before any and all drivers using **module_init()**.

---

> Is there any place where the device tree device nodes binding order is updated.

No, you're making an assumption that has no foundation.
Your unstated premise that the order of nodes in the Device Tree somehow determines the initialization order of device drivers and/or device probing/binding is false.

See [The order in which the device-tree text file is written, does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609713/the-order-in-which-the-device-tree-text-file-is-written-does-it-matter)

---

> How the device tree device nodes binding order is decided?

"*Binding order*" is essentially determined by the order that driver initialization routines are executed.
The order of nodes in the flattened Device Tree determines nothing.
The Linux kernel avoids relying on the Device Tree for any ordering because only a few processor architectures use the DT. Those arches only use the DT to provide system/device configuration.
See **Documentation/devicetree/usage-model.rst**.

On a running system, inspect **/proc/device-tree/**, and find the subdirectory for your peripheral bus. Whatever sequence the nodes were ordered in the source DT is not preserved here.

---

Within an initcall level, the order that driver routines are executed is determined at kernel build time.
This is documented in the kernel source in **/include/linux/init.h**:

```
 initcalls are now grouped by functionality into separate subsections.  
 Ordering inside the subsections is determined by link order.
```

---

If your drivers do happen to use the same init level, then for a solution see
[What is the Linux built-in driver load order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642330/what-is-the-linux-built-in-driver-load-order)
and
[Serializing the driver's init call order, which were registered at the same init level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895809/serializing-the-drivers-init-call-order-which-were-registered-at-the-same-init)

Comment: You forgot to mention the deferred probe execution that very often occurs when a consumer requests GPIO line. If the driver (of the consumer) written correctly, it will get that error and defer probe of itself.

Comment: Follow the link in the last line of the answer.